# How to navigate back from a Fragment to an Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

If I use this code in a Fragment,

```
ActionBar actionBar=((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
```

I get an error. If I'm in an Activity, the hamburger icon looks like this

[image]

but if I'm in a Fragment, the hamburger icon automatically changes to a back arrow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add a back button on Fragment,
just get parent activity with

```
getActivity()
```

then add

```
android:parentActivity".YourActivityName"
```

Which will add back button to your activity.

Or if you are trying to customize your ActionBar, make sure you are using AppComaptActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Navigation Drawer ?

Use this in your activity file

```
  setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

If you need to use DrawerIndicator then use this below code

```
mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
```

To disable Drawerindicator

```
 mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
```

If you want to change the Doggle button based on click

Use this code :

```
final View.OnClickListener originalToolbarListener = mDrawerToggle.getToolbarNavigationClickListener();

getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onBackStackChanged() {
        if (condition) {
            mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);

            mDrawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                }
            });
        } else {
            toolbar.setTitle("");
            mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);

            mDrawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(originalToolbarListener);
        }
    }
});
```